# How to explore path in neo4j by filtering nodes' property?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, gremlin

I query nodes in Gremlin like this:

```
g.V('vitamin a').bothE().order().by("confidence", desc).inV().limit(5).
flatMap(bothE().order().by("confidence", desc).inV().limit(5)).
flatMap(bothE().order().by("confidence", desc).inV().limit(4)).
flatMap(bothE().order().by("confidence", desc).inV().limit(3)).
path().by(__.valueMap(true))
```

How to query this in Cypher?

Comment: I have the same problem...

Comment: For those of us who know Cypher but not Gremlin, can you describe what that Gremlin statement is trying to do?